# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Google.Apis.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to connect Google Drive Service client but I am getting this exception and I am not getting any solution. Here is my code.

```
public static DriveService GetDriveClient()
    {
        var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientID, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                , scopes
                , Environment.UserName
                , CancellationToken.None
                , new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
            ).Result;

        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = appName,
        });

        return service;
    }
```

I am getting following error in yellow screen:

Invalid Application name
Parameter name: ApplicationName

Comment: first tell us about inner exception. what you got inside inner exception.

Comment: Innerexception is null

Answer (score 1):

The `appName` value you are using to set `ApplicationName` is invalid.

`ApplicationName` is used directly in the HTTP `User-Agent` header, so must conform to the `token` specification in on [RFC2616 page 17](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-17).

As of release [v1.27.0](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/releases/tag/v1.27.0) this uses the [System.Net.Http.Headers.ProductInfoHeaderValue.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.productinfoheadervalue.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to check validity. See [BaseClientService.cs line 120](https://github.com/chrisdunelm/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/cd4c5f158e252be55f06a9d7872fde930711af7a/Src/Support/Google.Apis/Services/BaseClientService.cs#L120)

Comment: I have just followed the steps which are mentioned here...
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet
Can you plz explain me in simple way about solving this issue bcz this was working fine till yesterday?

Comment: As Kut-Paste-Done says, change the ApplicationName to something that doesn't include any spaces or a dot. The validation became stricter in the latest release v1.27.0; I'll see about getting the documentation updated so the example just works. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In the next hour or two we'll release v1.27.1 which will remove ApplicationName validation, reverting to release v1.26.0 behaviour. Once you upgrade to v1.27.1 the quickstart will work without changes.

Answer (score 0):

.NET doesn't like any special characters in the Application Name. 
I copied code from the Google API Quickstart and continually received errors.

```
//static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart"; //DOESN'T WORK!
static string ApplicationName = "oneWord";   //WORKS!
```

Possibly needs URL encoding or some other handling but the above fixed my problem.